# Full calendar add row in header

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar these days and I am not familiar with it, so I am trying to add a new row in the header, I tried with this

```
addButtons();

bindButtonActions();

function addButtons() {
    // create buttons
    var month = $("<span/>")
        .addClass("fc-button fc-button-month fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-state-active")
        .attr({
            unselectable: "on"
        })
        .text("moth");

    var week = $("<span/>")
        .addClass("fc-button fc-button-agendaWeek fc-state-default")
        .attr({
            unselectable: "on"
        })
        .text("week");

    var day = $("<span/>")
        .addClass("fc-button fc-button-agendaDay fc-state-default fc-corner-right")
        .attr({
            unselectable: "on"
        })
        .text("day");

    // create tr with buttons.
    // Please note, if you want the buttons to be placed at the center or right,
    // you will have to append more <td> elements
    var tr = $("<tr/>").append(
        $("<td/>")
            .addClass("fc-header-left")
            .append(month)
            .append(week)
            .append(day)
    );

    // insert row before title.
    $(".fc-header").find("tr:first").before(tr);
}

function bindButtonActions(){
    var date = new Date();
    // bind actions to buttons
    $(".fc-button-month, .fc-button-agendaWeek, .fc-button-agendaDay").on('click', function() {
        var view = "month";
        if ($(this).hasClass("fc-button-agendaWeek")) {
            view = "agendaWeek";
        } else if ($(this).hasClass("fc-button-agendaDay")) {
            view = "agendaDay";
        }

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', view);

    });
```

and it doesn't show the first row at all, I want to insert row before title, so the month,week,day,year appear in the first row, and the other thing in the second one

Comment: This: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/ and/or this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/customButtons/ will probably solve this problem much more simply for you.

Comment: yes i tried with custom button but the point is to add a new row in front of the header, so to be more specific i need 2 rows in the header

Comment: ththe custom buttons should dislplay month week day and year and be in the front row of the header , second row i have arrows and the today button

Comment: something like this fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/19qml7to/

Comment: That example in your JSFiddle seems to work nicely. Have I missed something? What's the problem with it (other than you spelled "month" incorrectly)? Perhaps a mockup image of how you want it to look would be helpful so we can understand better than a wordy description.

Comment: it works ok in the fiddle, but when i try to put it in my local code the first row doesn't appear, don't know why, the example in the fiddle is 3 years old , maybe the updated version of full calendar doesn't work that way anymore

Comment: have you checked your browser console for errors? This should be the first thing you do when something "doesn't work". If you debug a bit, you'll get a clue as to where precisely the problem is coming from. And which exact versions of fullCalendar/jQuery/momentJS are you using? Have you actually looked at the rendered HTML of the calendar to see if it matches the structure being referenced in that example? This is all relevant info which you can discover for yourself, but haven't mentioned.

Comment: in console when i try to execute this function addButtons(); it shows ,VM101:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: addButtons is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: so either you didn't define the function, or it's not in scope when you try to call it. And that doesn't answer any of my other questions

Comment: Anyway I figured it out after a couple of minutes looking at the newer HTML structure - see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML structure in fullCalendar 3.x is significantly changed from earlier versions. The code you posted above targets 2.x, so will no longer create the right items or append them in the right place.

You can figure this out by looking at the structure of the header elements, which have changed from using tables to divs. Also the "buttons" that example creates aren't really buttons, they're spans, and the fullCalendar button classes don't work on spans.

This version of the code works with 3.x:

```
function addButtons() {
    // create buttons
    var month = $("<button/>")
        .addClass("fc-button fc-button-month fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-state-active")
        .attr({
            unselectable: "on",
            type: "button"
        })
        .text("month");

    var week = $("<button/>")
        .addClass("fc-button fc-button-agendaWeek fc-state-default")
        .attr({
            unselectable: "on",
            type: "button"
        })
        .text("week");

    var day = $("<button/>")
        .addClass("fc-button fc-button-agendaDay fc-state-default fc-corner-right")
        .attr({
            unselectable: "on",
            type: "button"
        })
        .text("day");

    // create tr with buttons.
    // Please note, if you want the buttons to be placed at the center or right,
    // you will have to append more <td> elements
    var toolbar = $("<div/>")
      .addClass("fc-toolbar")
      .addClass("fc-header-toolbar")
      .append(
          $("<div/>")
            .addClass("fc-left")
            .append(month)
            .append(week)
            .append(day)
    );
    toolbar.append($("<div/>", { "class": "fc-clear"}));

    // insert row before title.
    $(".fc-header-toolbar").before(toolbar);
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/soreewrj/1/ for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Specify Header while calling the FullCalendar function,

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    }
});
```

Above code is not tested but you can do some experiment on this. Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this but it says url:undefined , please detailed explanation because i am new to this

Comment: @FestimDehar ignore that bit, I think it's just an example of the remainder of the options. You'd have to specify your URL obviously. The error is just because in this example it specifies the url via a `url` variable. Presumably your code doesn't define this. You can replace it with whatever you like. The header part is what's interesting in terms of your question.